# how to reinstall grub on ESX 4 system?

Tags: vmware-esx, grub

I rebooted my esx 4 server today and was greet by a single bit of text that said GRUB and it hung.  I am attempting to restore the MBR GRUB partition, but am having difficulties.  All i have is the ESX 4 installation ISO.  Can someone help me with the procedure to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by booting from the ESX 4 DVD, then stepping through the install until it loaded the storage drivers.  Then, ctrl-alt-F2 and this procedure:

```
# grub
grub> root (hd0,0)
grub> setup (hd0)
```

then rebooted and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to repair a linux install's boot loader before.  Can anyone confirm that this will work with ESX?

Comment: Doesn't help when you're stuck in a data center with no way to burn disks.